# HIghStock Chart not displaying when using 'StockChart'

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I've been trying to get this to work and I'm completely stuck. I think I've done everything properly. Included all needed file but my chart won't show when I use:

```
$('#index-container').highcharts('StockChart', {
```

my chart does not show. But when I use

```
$('#index-container').highcharts('Chart', {
```

chart shows but does not show the controls properly.

See my code below

```
$(function() {
                $.getJSON('get-chart-data.php?series=c&x=NSE&s=<?php echo $secsymbol ?>&callback=?', function (data) {

                    $('#index-container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                        rangeSelector: {
                            inputEnabled: true,
                            selected: 1
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'company'
                        },
                        series: [
                            {
                                name: 'symbol',
                                data: data,
                                type: 'area',
                                threshold: null,
                                tooltip: {
                                    valueDecimals: 2
                                },
                                fillColor: {
                                    linearGradient: {
                                        x1: 0,
                                        y1: 0,
                                        x2: 0,
                                        y2: 1
                                    },
                                    stops: [
                                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                        [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
            });
<div id="index-container" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="min-height:450px; min-width: 480px"></div>
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help this has been a pain the last three hours.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @Henry I have a little bit of experience with HighCharts, and asynch. I'd like to help you out.  I'll need a little more info though.  Highcharts gives you a few different options to load the chart.  Why have you chosen jquery?  Also I noticed that you are using a 'getJSON' request.  Can you explain that part of the code?  What are you expecting in return?  Where is the 'data' variable located?

Comment: You should also check if you load highstock file http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js instead of highcharts file